# New sd card doesnt work in my Android Alcatel one touch phone

Tags: sd-card

I purchased a new sd card for my Android phone to increase memory.  Its a 32 gb card, but my phone still says not enough memory when I try to download an app. I tried selecting sd card and it shows 32 gb available but still cant download apps.  Then I switched to internal memory just to see if that worked but it did not.  It shows I have 32 gb of memory but phone says not enough memory. I tried to format new sd card but still getting same message.  HELP!!

Comment: What android version are you on?  Older Android didn't support running apps off of SD cards.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't any problem with your SD card since it is recognized buy the phone. You know what else? Apps can't be placed on sd card without some help. Phone shows to you message 'not enough memory' because you lack internal memory where apps go when installing. So please rephrase your question. And check out this: 
[insufficient-memory' tag wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/insufficient-memory/info),

['app2sd' tag wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/app2sd/info),

[link2sd tag wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/link2sd/info),

[adoptable storage tag wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/adoptable-storage/info)

Answer (score 0):

Some data can be stored on SD cards and others not. This depends on how the SD card is integrated in your device.

A rule of thumb is, that apps should be stored on the internal storage of your phone (often this is the only possibility). While pictures and music can be also located on the SD card.

I can not read this from your posting, but maybe you should try to move such user data manually to your new SD card to make space available on your internal memory.